# Css wrapping of two div without edit html

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a display flex with three div, it's a component but I can't edit it because it is shared betwenn multiple teams.

I can only update CSS, in the fiddle first part is the actual layout and second part is the expected one.

With only CSS I need to update:

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="square blue">
    x
  </div>
  <div class="square red">
   x
  </div>
  <div class="square yellow">
    x
  </div>
</div>
```

To obtain the results render by the second html (See JSFiddle) :

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="square blue">
  x
  </div>
  <div class="square">
   <div class="square red">
    x
   </div>
   <div class="square yellow">
    x
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h8o523tL/33/

Comment: Css can't manipulate html-elements, javascript can do this if needed. Can you not change the html generated in server side?

Comment: No i want  add some CSS style to obtain the results render by the second html you can see my JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS grid and you will obtain the layout you want:

```css
.flex {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
   "blue red" 
   "blue yellow";
}

.blue {
  grid-area: blue;
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  grid-area: red;
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  grid-area: yellow;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="square blue">
    x
  </div>
  <div class="square red">
    x
  </div>
  <div class="square yellow">
    x
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

For more browser support you can try this:

```css
.flex {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.blue {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex:before {
  content:"";
  min-height:1px;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  width:50%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="square blue">
    blue
  </div>
  <div class="square red">
    red
  </div>
  <div class="square yellow">
    yellow
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need compatibility with IE10 :)